# Finding integers $a,b$ and $c$ such that $a^3+b^3 = c^3$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

We are learning about the the Pythagorean Theorem in class. It says that $a^2+b^2 = c^2$. My homework problem says the following:

> Find integers $a,b$ and $c$  such that $a^3+b^3 = c^3$.

How do I solve this equation?

I've been starting with $(3,4,5), (4,4,5)$ etc. Basically I am starting Pythogrean triples.

Comment: Are you sure it says that? There are not such numbers (apart from treivial ones).

Comment: By trial and error. It has only very trivial solutions.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott right, just realized that and edited my comment.

Comment: How trivial are we talking about?

Comment: @Valtteri: To answer that would pretty much give away the solution. I’m trying to think of a good hint.

Comment: You can use this [lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat's_Last_Theorem).

Comment: I think $a=b=c=1$ would work.

Comment: @julien, it doesn't say positive

Comment: @loxststudent How? $1^3+1^3=2 \not = 1^3$

Comment: No, $a=b=c=1$ does not work: $1^3+1^3\ne 1^3$.

Comment: But we can say that Pythagorean triples are not a good starting point?

Comment: @Valtteri I did not say it completely solved the problem... But it helps to know that there are no solutions $(x,y,z)$ with $x>0$, $y>0$, $z>0$. Hence no solutions with $x<0$, $y<0$ and $z<0$ either.

Comment: @julien Very true

Answer (score 3):

HINT: It is known that the equation $a^3+b^3=c^3$ has **no** solutions in which $a,b$, and $c$ are all positive integers. It does have infinitely many solutions in integers, but all of them have one of two or three basic forms (depending on how you count) and are rather trivial.

Comment: It is $(a,-a,0)$?

Comment: @loxststudent: Oops! You found a second form; very good. Yes, that works, but there’s another set of solutions with the $0$ elsewhere.

Comment: i think it would be $(a,0,a)$?

Comment: @loxststudent: That’s right; also $\langle 0,a,a\rangle$, if you want to count that case separately from $\langle a,0,a\rangle$.

Answer (score 0):

If $a=0,b^2=c^2\implies b=\pm c$  and $b^3=c^3\implies b=c$

$\implies b=c$

So, $(0,b,b)$ is a solution

Similarly, $(b,0,b)$ is a solution

If $c\ne0, \left(\frac ac\right)^2+\left(\frac bc\right)^2=1$

$\implies \frac ac<1\implies \left(\frac ac\right)^2>\left(\frac ac\right)^3$

Similarly, $\left(\frac bc\right)^2>\left(\frac bc\right)^3$

$\implies \left(\frac ac\right)^3+\left(\frac bc\right)^3<1$